# How do i use tm structure to add minutes to current time?

Tags: c++, time

Currently I am trying to add minutes to current time, but how do I do it? I read through some tutorials and all but still have no idea how to do it.

So my code goes..

```
time_t now = time(0);

tm* localtm = localtime(&now);
cout << "Current time : " << asctime(localtm) << endl;
```

My program will sort of "run" in minutes which is + 1 minute every loop..

So lets say there is 255 loops and it is 255 minutes.. I store it in Minute.

I tried adding it this way but the time remained the same as the current time..

```
localtm->tm_min + Minute;
mktime (localtm);
cout << "End of program time : " << asctime(localtm) << endl;
```

I am wondering how should I do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Add it to the time_t instead.

Comment: so do i do time_t + Minute; then mktime (localtm); ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    time_t now = time(0);

    size_t Minutes = 255;

    time_t newTime = now + (60 * Minutes);

    struct tm tNewTime;
    memset(&tNewTime, '\0', sizeof(struct tm));
    localtime_r(&newTime, &tNewTime);

    cout << asctime(&tNewTime) << endl;
}
```

Comment: good for using the struct tm, as the OP asked!

Answer (score 6):

C++ 11:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point  time_now = 
                                                      std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        time_now += std::chrono::hours(10);
        time_t c_time_format = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_now);
        std::string str_time = std::ctime(& c_time_format);
        std::cout<<str_time<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

To compile this code ,you shoud include headrs chrono ctime .

You can use "seconds(val),minutes(val),hours(val) etc"

With any question,you can visit the following :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/system_clock/

Comment: Not using the struct tm as the OP asked